Assert.Equal() Failure in xunit tesing
given below was my code for xuit tesing
        [Fact]
        public async Task ProcessRequestTestNotFoundObjectResult()
        {
            //Arrange 
            var mockedRequesBody = new WebHookBody
            {
                entryId = "test"
            };
            var memoryBody = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mockedRequesBody)));
            var httpRequestMock = HttpRequestDataMockFactory.CreateHttpRequestDataMock();
            var expectedResult = new NotFoundResult();
            var _contentfulClientTest = new Mock<ContentfulCollection<dynamic>>();
            _contentfulClientMock.Setup(x => x.GetEntries(It.IsAny<Contentful.Core.Search.QueryBuilder<dynamic>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(_contentfulClientTest.Object));

            httpRequestMock.SetBody(memoryBody);

            //Act 
            var result = await _eventTriggerService.ProcessRequest(httpRequestMock);

            //Assert
            Assert.Equal(expectedResult, result);
        }

Here my problem is in assert section while checking both are equal

i am expecting that these assert.Equal() was true

You are comparing two object references. Not their property values. Since their references are different (I.e. not the same object) the comparison will be false. Try Assert.Equal(expectedResult.StatusCode, result.StatusCode);

This question is similar to: xUnit tests failing to Assert.Equal two equal values. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You have to use             Assert.Equal(expectedResult.StatusCod, result.StatusCode); Here you need to compare there status codes or their string response not the complete object.

You could also use Assert.Equivalent(expectedResult, result);.

You can also use Assert.Equal(expectedResult.Value, result.Value) if you want to compare response.

@RithwikBojja that would not work since NotFoundResult doesn't have a property called Value.  See documentation.

@RithwikBojja When i use resut.StatusCode or result.Value it shows error like IActionResult dose not contain definition for StatusCode

You are comparing two object references. Not their property values. Since their references are different (I.e. not the same object) the comparison will be false.
You could compare with Assert.Equivalent however it appears also that ProcessRequest returns IActionResult. So you need to cast to StatusCodeResult.
[Fact]
public async Task ProcessRequestTestNotFoundObjectResult()
{
    //Arrange 
    var mockedRequesBody = new WebHookBody
    {
        entryId = "test"
    };
    var memoryBody = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mockedRequesBody)));
    var httpRequestMock = HttpRequestDataMockFactory.CreateHttpRequestDataMock();
    var expectedResult = new NotFoundResult();
    var _contentfulClientTest = new Mock<ContentfulCollection<dynamic>>();
    _contentfulClientMock.Setup(x => x.GetEntries(It.IsAny<Contentful.Core.Search.QueryBuilder<dynamic>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(_contentfulClientTest.Object));

    httpRequestMock.SetBody(memoryBody);

    //Act 
    var result = (await _eventTriggerService.ProcessRequest(httpRequestMock)) as StatusCodeResult;

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(expectedResult.StatusCode, result.StatusCode);
        
    //This should work as well since now both types have the same public properties.
    //Assert.Equivalent(expectedResult, result);
}


Hey sani huttunen , this StatusCodeResult also give same error

And what error is that exactly?
